# Anyway to avoid buttons when it comes to page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have created a program that runs through a flow using C#

At the moment it contains a large amount of buttons to make certain panels visible etc.

I was wondering if I could make the page refresh when the user checks a checkbox?

Comment: You're giving us very little to work with, but assuming you're talking about an ASP.NET application, have a look at `AutoPostBack`.

Comment: Yes I am talking about ASP.NET sorry I'm rather new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the CheckBox' [`AutoPostBack`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.90).aspx) to `true`(default is `false`).

```
<asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                Text="Check/uncheck me for a postback"
                OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            //do whatever you want to on first time page load
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to `refresh` your panel on check of `checkbox`, you can do something like below:-

```
<asp:CheckBox id"chkVisible" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkVisible_OnCheckedChanged" Text="Test for Page referesh" />
```

You need to set `AutoPostBack` property to `True` for refreshing your page.